# What does void (* const ivt[])(void) mean?

Tags: c++, c

I'm reading the book Embedded Systems Architecture by Daniele Lacamera. In Chapter 4,The Boot-Up code

```
__attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector"))) void (* const ivt[])(void) =
{
    (void (*) (void))(END_STACK),
    isr_reset,
    //...
};
```

I don't understand `void (* const ivt[])(void)`, is it the array? If it's the array what does `(void)` mean?

Comment: "declare ivt as array of const pointer to function (void) returning void" according to [cedcl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*+const+ivt%5B%5D%29%28void%29)

Comment: Yes, `ivt` is the array. Specifically it's the interrupt vector table, which is an array of pointers to interrupt handlers. In other words, `ivt` is an array of function pointers. The first `void` in `void (* const ivt[])(void)` means that the interrupt handler does not return a value. The second `void` means that the interrupt handler is a function that takes zero parameters.

Comment: It means the person who wrote this code didn't know what a `typedef` was.

Comment: [cdecl comes for help](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*+const+ivt%5B%5D%29%28void%29)

Answer (score 4):

Install the tool cdecl and ask it to explain things to you:

```
mrvn@ryzen:~$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain void (* const ivt[])(void)
declare ivt as array of const pointer to function (void) returning void
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the declaration of an interrupt vector table for a microcontroller, likely an ARM Cortex M.

- `__attribute__ ((section(".isr_vector")))` is a non-standard gcc extension assigning the variable to a specific section in memory (absolute address). You'll find `.isr_vector` in the corresponding linker script.
- Regarding `void (* const ivt[])(void)`:

  - `void (*f)(void)` would create a function pointer (to a function taking no arguments and returning no value - which is true for all interrupt service routines).
  - `void (*f[])(void)` would create an array of function pointers. Since no size of the array is specified, the size will be determined by the following initializer list.
  - `void (* const ivt[])(void)` adding the `const` keyword will make the array of function pointers read-only, which is a requirement since it should get allocated in flash and never changed in run-time.
- `(void (*) (void))(END_STACK)` could cast an integer `END_STACK` to a function pointer. Alternatively this could also be a dirty, strictly speaking invalid cast from a struct or other object into a function pointer. The target appears to be an ARM core where the default stack pointer is stored at the bottom of the interrupt vector table, then then sp is set automatically by the hardware.
- `isr_reset` is the first interrupt, the reset vector.

Answer (score 1):

It is an array named `ivt` holding constant pointers to functions that take no parameters and return `void`.

Answer (score 1):

> i dot't understading void (* const ivt[])(void), is it the array?

Yes, `ivt` is an array of constant pointers to function that accepts no arguments and returns nothing.

The type of elements of `ivt` array is

```
 void (* const)(void)
```

which means constant pointer to function which accepts no arguments and returns nothing.

> If it's the array what does (void) mean?

It means function accepts no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`ivt` is an array of constant pointers to functions that takes no parameters and have the return type `void`.

Perhaps an example might help understand the situation better:

```
void func1()
{
    std::cout<<"func1 called"<<std::endl;
}
void func2()
{
    std::cout<<"func2 called"<<std::endl;
}
void foo()
{
    std::cout<<"foo called"<<std::endl;
}

void foobar()
{
    
}
int main()
{
//----------------vvv---------------------------------> ivt is an array of const pointers to a function with return type of void and having 0 parameters
    void (* const ivt[])(void) = {func1, func2, foo};  
//--------------------------------^^^^^--^^^^^--^^^---> add pointers  to these 3 functions into the array 


   //iterate through the elements in the array and call the member functinos 
   for(void (*const PTR)(void): ivt)
   {
       PTR();
       
//-----------v---------------------------------------->this assignment won't work because pointers are themselves const so you can make them point to another function
       //PTR = foobar; 
   }
    
}
```

The [output](https://onlinegdb.com/JRBVMK7n_) of the above program is:

```
func1 called
func2 called
foo called
```