# What does clever1 and goo_ptr in this c code mean?

Tags: c, function-pointers

```c
int (*clever1(int (* (*goo_ptr)(int, int, int (*)(int, int), int(*)(int, int)))(int, int), int a, int b, int (*a_fptr)(int, int), int(*b_fptr)(int, int) ))(int, int) {
   return goo_ptr(a,b,b_fptr,a_fptr);
}
```

what is type of clever1? what is type of goo_ptr? I can't understand the code.

Comment: Replace one function pointer after another by a `typedef` till it is clear. Who came up with this code?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does void (\* const ivt\[\])(void) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72312821/what-does-void-const-ivtvoid-mean). This dupe also have `cdecl` .

Comment: With `typedef int (*FUNC1)(int, int); typedef FUNC1 (*FUNC2)(int, int, FUNC1, FUNC1);` the function can be rewritten as `FUNC1 clever1(FUNC2 goo_ptr, int a, int b, FUNC1 a_fptr, FUNC1 b_fptr)`.

Comment: This isn't a puzzle site.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`clever1` is a function that returns a pointer to a function. The returned function returns an `int` and takes two `int`s as arguments.

`clever1` function takes 5 arguments - `goo_ptr`, `a`, `b`, `b_fptr` and `a_fptr`.

`goo_ptr` is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function. That returned function returns an `int` and takes two `int`s as arguments. `goo_ptr` points to a function that takes 4 arguments. The first two arguments have type `int`, the last two are pointers to functions that return an `int` and take two arguments of the same type `int`.

`a` and `b` are both just `int`s.

`a_fptr` and `b_fptr` are both pointers to functions returning `int` and taking two `int`s as arguments.

Looks like a common theme here - take two `int`s return an `int`.